# Confused about the variable scope in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, state

I define a const before return(  but when I try to render it, get error its undefined.

I am struggling with the concepts of REACT. Any constants or vars defined before RETURN are not available for rendering in  ??

Is it that only setState variables are available for rendering?

Here is the code.. I saved var countryname from API data, but when i try to render it, says UNDEFINED

./src/components/CountryPanel.jsx
Line 83:49:  'countryname' is not defined  no-undef

```
export default function CountryPanel(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  let countryCode = props.countryCode

  let url =
      "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotal=" + countryCode;
  const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState({});
  const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState("");
    
  useEffect(() => {
   
    getData(url);

    async function getData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      let data = await response.json(); // convert to json
      const countryname = data.countrydata[0].info.title;
      delete data.countrydata[0].info;
      setCountryName(countryname);
      setGlobalData(data.countrydata[0]);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h3>
        Stats for: {countryCode} {countryName} {countryname}
      </h3>
```

> > > last of three is UNDEFINED although I saved it from API data
> > > const countryname = data.countrydata[0].info.title; (..name - n lowercase)

Comment: can you please add your code?

Comment: My question was: Why react is saying 'countryname is Undefined'. I saved it from the API data before the 'return'.

 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h3>
        Stats for: {countryCode} {countryName} {countryname}

Comment: I did not get an answer to my question which was:

Why can't I render/display {countryname}  ??? Why do I have to save it to STATE to render it?? IS there a way to render it without saving to STATE??


 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h3>
        Stats for: {countryCode} {countryName} {countryname}

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `countryname` ( separate from `countryName`) is scoped only to your function `getData`. Variables in JavaScript are scoped to the function/block they are defined within, depending on how you declare them (var vs let/const). In this case, `countryName` is available everywhere within your component, while `countryname` is only available within `getData`. This is a JavaScript-ism, and has nothing to do with you using React.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. So, is it correct to say to use countryname after 'RETURN (', it has to be Set in state?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here. There is no way to return `countryname` in this case. You are passing it to `setCountryName`, which will have the effect of giving `countryName` the same value as `countryname` on the next render. The `useEffect` hook will not return whatever your callback returns, so you can't get it back up to the same scope. Even if you defined `countryname` outside of `useEffect`, it doesn't have a value until after the promise resolves. Which means it won't be available by the time you try to return from `render`.

Comment: If you mean you can use `countryname` after you return, that technically isn't really true either. After your current return your element (returning the elements that will render), none of those variables are still in scope. React will asynchronously (eventually) assign the value `countryname` to something that can be used to retrieve `counrtryName` on the next render. The variable `countryname` can never be used outside of `setData` as things are right now.

Comment: Nor do I think there's any reason to (or any value in it). Just get rid of the `{countryname}` in your render, and you should be fine. You are setting `countryName` to be the exact same value as `countryname` (by virtue of passing it to `setCountryName`). So there is no reason to reference `countryname` outside of `setData`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `setState` ain't variable, but we need `const` to define `state`.

eg: `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);`

`isLoading` by default is `true` and mutable with `setIsLoading`.

---

Another example is `const foo = 'bar';`

In this scenario, `foo` is not able to change to other value.

---

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That's how I defined state as shown above